# How to render multiple icons from a data component in a Card

Tags: reactjs

I want to create dynamic cards with the datas imported from the data.js component.
The problem I'm facing right know is to figure out how i can display the crypto icons in it.
I've just imported one of the for demonstrating porpuses.

But how can i import them all into the cards. So lets say, if there are just 1 icons in the data source, it just displays one. But in other cards there might be more.

Thinking about a ternary operator to solve this issue?

This is the card component below.

```
import React from 'react'
import data from "./data";
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap';

function PersonalCard() {
    const cards = data.map((item, id) => {
        console.log(item)
        return (
            <Card key={id} style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Img alt="crypto icons" variant="top" src={`./images/${item.crypto.btc}`} />
            <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title>{item.title}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                {item.text}
                </Card.Text>
                <Button variant="primary">{item.button}</Button>
            </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        )
    })

    return (
        <div>
            {cards}
        </div>
    )
}

export default PersonalCard
```

Below is the data.js. Array of objects.

```
export default [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Brack.ch", 
        text: "wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
        crypto: {
            btc: "btc.png",
            eth: "eth.png",
            xrp: "xrp.png",
        },
        button: "zum Onlineshop"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Brack.ch", 
        text: "wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
        crypto: {
            btc: "btc.png",
            eth: "eth.png",
        },
        button: "zum Onlineshop"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Brack.ch", 
        text: "wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
        crypto: {
            btc: "btc.png",
            xrp: "xrp.png",
        },
        button: "zum Onlineshop"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: "Brack.ch", 
        text: "wir akzeptieren folgende Kryptowährungen",
        crypto: {
            btc: "btc.png",
        },
        button: "zum Onlineshop"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values(item.crypto)` to get a list of image names (no need to worry about the number of images it will have) and use `map` to iterate over them and display.

Try like this.

```
function PersonalCard() {
  const cards = data.map((item, id) => {
    console.log(item);
    return (
      <Card key={id} style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
        {Object.values(item.crypto).map((imgName) => (
          <Card.Img
            alt="crypto icons"
            variant="top"
            src={`./images/${imgName}`}
          />
        ))}
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>{item.title}</Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>{item.text}</Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">{item.button}</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  });

  return <div>{cards}</div>;
}
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-sara-yrjhn?file=/src/App.js)

[image]

Comment: @Remo Furrer, check this out !!

Comment: @Remo Furrer, can you please mark this as the answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this , if you want to add icons in list.
Here you can import various icons and store it in a object of Array with various properties and use it with the help of map function.

```
 const arrobj = [
    { id: 1, imgs: <FaLinkedin />, name: "LinkedIn" },
    { id: 2, imgs: <FaDiscord />, name: "Discord" },
    { id: 3, imgs: <FaTwitterSquare />, name: "Twitter" },
    { id: 4, imgs: <FaGithubSquare />, name: "Github" },
    { id: 5, imgs: <FaFacebookSquare />, name: " Facebook" },


  ];
 const listitem = arrobj.map((arr) =>
    <div >
      <li className='flex p-1 mx-auto' size={13} key={arr.id}>
       <div className='px-2'> {arr.imgs}</div> {arr.name}

      </li>
    </div>

  );

return (
       <>
                 <div className='p-1'>{listitem}</div>

       </>
);
```